# Using array.map properly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am not sure why my array.map function returns undefined but my for loop returns the result.  When I console log map it displays:

> Tom
>   Dick
>   Harry

and when console log for loop it shows

> ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']

Not sure if this is the problem of showing undefiend.

```
var friends = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"];
var secondLevelFriends = ["Anne", "Harry", "Quinton"];
var allUsers = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Anne", "Quinton", "Katie", "Mary"];

function findPotentialFriends(existingFriends) {
  return function(x) {
    // existingFriends.map(function(elem) {
    //   if(elem === x) return false;
    //   else return true;
    // })
    for(var i = 0; i < existingFriends.length; i++) {
      if(existingFriends[i] === x) return false;
      else return true;
    }
  }
}

var isNotAFriend = findPotentialFriends( friends );
isNotAFriend(allUsers[0]); // false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your for loop has some logic problems. it should be written as so:

```
var foundFriend = false;
for(var i = 0; i < existingFriends.length; i++) {
  if (existingFriends[i] === x)
  {
    foundFriend = true;
    break;
  }
}
return !foundFriend;
```

The reason why `isNotAFriend` evaluates to `undefined` is because you forgot a `return` statement. Furthermore, the `Arrays.map` just simply takes each element of the array, passes it into the function, then creates a new array based on what your function returns. What you might be searching for is perhaps `Array.some` see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Example:

```js
var friends = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"];
var secondLevelFriends = ["Anne", "Harry", "Quinton"];
var allUsers = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Anne", "Quinton", "Katie", "Mary"];

function findPotentialFriends(existingFriends) {
  return function(x) {
    return !existingFriends.some(function(elem) {
      return elem === x;
    });
  }
}

var isNotAFriend = findPotentialFriends( friends );
console.log(isNotAFriend(allUsers[0]));
```

Comment: I think what he's really looking for is `Array.some()`.

Comment: Yes. Thanks I'll go change that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the `return` statements in the callback just return to `map()`, they don't return to the original caller. `map()` collects all these return values into an array and returns this, but you never do anything with the result of `existingfriends.map()`.

Javascript has a built-in function to search an array for a matching element, [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). It returns `-1` if no match is found.

So you can simply write:

```js
var friends = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"];
var secondLevelFriends = ["Anne", "Harry", "Quinton"];
var allUsers = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Anne", "Quinton", "Katie", "Mary"];

function findPotentialFriends(existingFriends) {
  return function(x) {
   return existingFriends.indexOf(x) == -1;   
  }
}

var isNotAFriend = findPotentialFriends(friends);
console.log(isNotAFriend(allUsers[0])); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `return` in `map()` function .Its one of the new function inside the  return function .so apply with return this also.

```js
var friends = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"];
var secondLevelFriends = ["Anne", "Harry", "Quinton"];
var allUsers = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Anne", "Quinton", "Katie", "Mary"];

function findPotentialFriends(existingFriends) {
  return function(x) {
   return existingFriends.map(function(elem) {
  if(elem === x) return false;
     else return true;
    })
   // for(var i = 0; i < existingFriends.length; i++) {
    //  if(existingFriends[i] === x) return false;
     // else return true;
    //}
  }
}

var isNotAFriend = findPotentialFriends(friends);
console.log(isNotAFriend(allUsers[0])); // false
```